# apache, mod_wsgi: cannot open shared object file

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, mod-wsgi

$ /etc/init.d/httpd restart

```
Starting httpd: httpd: 
Syntax error on line 205 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: 
Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: 
/etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so: cannot open shared object file: 
No such file or directory
```

file: httpd.conf

```
..
205: LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

Any ideas in how can i correct this error or how to share the file: "mod_wsgi.so", in order to be loaded and used by apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mod_wsgi is an a module to host Python applications using the WSGI interface.

If you're not going to do that, just comment out the line. If you do want to run it, try making a fresh install of mod_wsgi. There's information at [the modwsgi page](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/)

Comment: yea, problem solved: I installed an older version of mod_wsgi 2.0, to get working woth Apache 2.2.2 and Python 2.5.

Comment: Why install an older version. Lastest version still works with those Apache and Python versions.